# Converting x86 to Y86

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, y86

I'm trying to figure out to convert this x86 assembly code to Y86 form:

Given the c program:

```
  int sum(int x) {
     if (x == 0 || x ==1) {
        return 1;
     } else {
        return x + sum(x-1);
     }
  }
```

The following x86-64 assembly code is generated:

```
sum:
    cmpl $1, %rdi
    ja .L8
    movl $1, %eax
    ret
.L8:
    pushq %rbx
    movl %edi, %ebx
    leal -1(%rdi), %edi
    call sum
    addl %ebx, %eax
    popq %rbx
    ret
```

How can I convert this to Y86-64 assembly code that does the same thing?

Thank you!

Comment: well, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can convert by replacing each instruction with a short sequence of y86 instructions which does exactly the same thing.

y86 is Turing complete, but very crippled, so *in general* you can't always *easily* convert.  Some single x86 instructions might need an entire loop or very long function to implement, but that's not the case for any of your instructions.  Each of them can be transliterated to one or a few y86 instructions.  (Some might need a scratch register; I forget if y86 has compare with immediate or only mov-immediate to register.)

Your code doesn't have any multiplies, shifts, or `bsf`, or floating-point, or anything else that y86 doesn't have (and would need a loop to emulate).

Look up each x86 instruction in the instruction-set reference manual ([like this online version](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/), or this [older one](http://x86.renejeschke.de/) where not having AVX/AVX2 instructions means less to wade through.  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to Intel and AMD's PDF manuals.)  **Look at the Operation section** where pseudo-code describes the exact effect of the instruction on the architectural state.  That's the behaviour you want to implement using y86 instructions.

As an example, I forget if y86 has `push` / `pop`, but if not you can always manipulate `rsp` directly and load/store.  e.g. `sub $8, %rsp` ; `movrm  %rbx, (rsp)` is `push` (except it clobbers flags where x86's `push` doesn't).